# How to export data from Table1 to Table2 just before delete ,using Triggers in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

What I want to know if there is any way by which, I can simply transfer whole record from table1 to table2.

The data structure and type in both the tables are same

- I don't want to select all columns one by one and then replace their value.
- I don't want to mention the column that needs to be updated.
- it should just replace the whole record.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a trigger like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRANSFER_TRIGGER
BEFORE DELETE
ON TABLE1
BEGIN

INSERT INTO TABLE2 (SELECT * FROM TABLE1);

END;
```